# How can I use a nodejs library from c++?

Tags: c++, node.js

I'm working with nodejs and want to run the program I made in C ++, is this possible to do ?, so far have found information on how to run C ++ libraries in nodejs, but nothing that allows me to use the tools of nodejs in c ++

Comment: This is a duplicate of a previous question where you didn't provide much in the way of examples. Can you add example code here that represents what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

nodejs is a standalone execution environment.  You run it from the command line as its own process, it fires up the nodejs interpreter and then that interpreter loads the script of your choice and runs it.  It does not come with a method of linking it into your own C++ program.  So, here are some other types of options:

1. From your C++ program, you could run your nodejs program as a separate process with spawn or exec and retrieve any output from the nodejs program (say an output file) or have it write to a communication channel such as stdout such that your C++ program could retrieve the output.
2. From your C++ program, you could start up your nodejs program and your nodejs program could then start a server (plain socket server, http server, socket.io server, etc...) by which the C++ program could send requests to the nodejs server and then retrieve the response.  You would just have the nodejs server listen to a predetermined port number such as 8088 and then your C++ program could connect to localhost on port 8088.
3. nodejs itself has a plug-in mechanism by which you can call C++ code from within nodejs.  In fact, may parts of the nodejs runtime (such as file I/O) are actually implemented in C++ and nodejs can call them via this plugin interface.  Note, this does not allow you to call an arbitrary nodejs app from within a C++ app.  This allows a nodejs app to call some code that is implemented in C++.  You can think of it like nodejs calling a function implemented in a DLL that happens to be written in C++.